# When should I use Factory<T> instead of Provider<T>

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

The Dagger documentation shows using a `Provider<Filter>` to get `Filter` instances, which appears to make perfect sense.

I am writing a `ListAdapter` which instantiates Views, which I'd like Dagger to inject.  I'm tempted to inject a `Provider<ViewType>` into my `ListAdapter`, and call `mViewProvider.get()` to instantiate views.

However, the Dagger documentation says:

> Injecting `Provider<T>` has the possibility of creating confusing code, and may be a design smell of mis-scoped or mis-structured objects in your graph.  Often you will want to use a `Factory<T>` or a `Lazy<T>` or re-organize the lifetimes and structure of your code to be able to just inject a `T`

I can see how I *could* use a Factory, in a similar manner to that required when using assisted injection.

But what advantage would using my own `Factory<T>` have over using Dagger's `Provider<T>`, given I'd have to write the former myself?

Comment: AFAIK Factory implies you get a new object each time.  Provider implies pooling is an option (which is often better), though you generally need a Factory when a new object is needed.  Lazy is an on-demand factory for one object.

Comment: Are Factories still applicable in Dagger2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Provider<T>` has a very concrete meaning in the system.  It is a delegated constructor of a Graph-managed object.  `Provider<T>` has specific guarantees/behaviour and I generally recommend against injecting `Provider<T>` unless you are supporting some legacy situation that requires it.

`Factory<T>` is an example - FooFactory is more accurate, because the intent of this is that you not use hand-rolled factories, but instead use something like `AutoFactory` (http://github.com/google/auto) to generate factories that create objects.  Then you don't have to write your own, but `AutoFactory` was not yet built when these docs were written.

Ultimately the reason is primarily code-clarity and long-term maintenance.  Using dagger's instance management as a de-facto Factory of instances is possible, but limited, as it can only work with instances that have injected dependencies.  Call-stack dependencies cannot be supported without adding another scope, or graph layer.  That fact has, in Guice, often caused people to use extra scopes to shoe-horn call-stack dependencies into object instance (provision) dependencies by playing games with custom scopes and complexifying their object graph and layering just to get some free code.

It was to solve this that (in guice) Assisted-Injection and (in Dagger) AutoFactory was created - so you could do the more semantically clearer thing that didn't depend on framework internals, but get it automatically done for you.

Not using `Provider<T>` is an opinion. You *are* free to do so if you wish, but it is not recommended practice.  Instead we recommend a solution like `AutoFactory` to get better named types, with clearer meaning in your system, that can support more flexible handling of call-stack state.

Comment: Nice, but AutoFactory does not appear to be in Maven Central yet (value & service do)

Comment: Crap - I forgot we delayed release because we hadn't fleshed out as many of the tests as we'd hoped.  I'll push on that.

Comment: Pushing again to hopefully get autofactory released soon?

Comment: Heh.  We have some active users now, I think we can roll a release within the next week or two.

Comment: I have released auto-factory 0.1-beta1 to maven and it is in the central repo now.

Comment: @ChristianGruber Why, six years later, `AutoFactory` and `AutoService` are still being released as beta?

Comment: You'd have to ask that team, but generally speaking, that's a pretty common pattern at Google, as a signal that APIs may change. I also know there was a hope to rewrite AutoFactory pretty substantially, but they never prioritized it.  google.com/github/truth only released 1.0 a few weeks ago, after a bazillion years as beta.  Feel free to file an issue asking for a 1.0 AutoFactory. :) (I'm no longer at Google and cannot do anything about this but join your complaint)