# how can I inject a dependency in a method?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm a beginner with dependency injection.. specifically Dagger 2. I'm trying to figure out if/how I can do something like this:

```
@Inject
public void someMethodName(int someInteger, SomeObject dependency){
 // do something with the dependency. 
}
```

Or do I need to put that dependency in as a class var? any help with this would be greatly appreciated. also in this case the variable someInteger is not a dependency, but is being added by the caller... does that matter?

can I call it like this:

```
this.someMethodName(5);
```

android studio does not like the above calling method (I'm assuming because I'm doing something wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create component which is annotated by @Component.
2. The Component accepts module which provides dependencies.
3. Every component's name that you create starts with Dagger prefix, e.g. for MyComponent.

Let's look at the following example:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = DemoApplicationModule.class)
    public interface ApplicationComponent {
        void inject(DemoApplication application);
    }
```

We created ApplicationComponent with single injection method. What we're saying is that we want to inject certain dependencies in DemoApplication.

Moreover, in the `@Component` annotations we specify module with provision methods.

This is like our module looks like:

```
@Module
public class DemoApplicationModule {
   private final Application application;

   public DemoApplicationModule(Application application) {
       this.application = application;
    }

  @Provides @Singleton SomeIntegerHandler provideIntegerHandler() {
       return new MySomeIntegerHandlerImpl();
  }
 }
```

What we're saying by creating DemoApplicationModule is that the module can provide desired dependencies in the injection place specified by our Component.

```
 public class DemoApplication extends Application {
   private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

   @Inject SomeIntegerHandler handler;

   @Override public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
         .demoApplicationModule(new DemoApplicationModule(this))
         .build();
     applicationComponent.inject(this);
     handler.someMethodName(5);
   }
  }
```

See documentation what you kind of dependencies you can obtain. Additionally to obtaining just raw instance you can obtain [Provider, Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778330/when-should-i-use-factoryt-instead-of-providert) or [Lazy](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html) instance.
http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html

You can also create scoped dependencis, the lifecycles of which depend on the lifecycle of injection places, like [Activities or Fragments](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/examples/android-activity-graphs/src/main/java/com/example/dagger/activitygraphs/PerActivity.java).

Hope I gave you the basic notion of what Dagger is.

Answer (score 1):

**YOU CAN USE SOME INTERFACE**

```
public interface myDependence{
   int myFunction(int value);
}
```

**NOW IMPLEMENT IN YOU CLASS**

```
public myClass implements MyDependence{
   @Override
   int myFunction(int value){
       // do something
   }
}
```